# How to use Apache Directory Studio with a proxy?

Tags: proxy, ldap, socks-proxy, apache-directory-studio

I want to connect to an LDAP server running on a server at `ldap.subnet.example.com` using [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/).

I am running Apache Directory Studio 2.0.0.v20200411-M15 with `java-14-openjdk` on Manjaro Linux.

Unfortunately, the LDAP server is only reachable from within the same subnet and I am outside this subnet (my host is `mypc.example.org`). I however can access the host `portal.subnet.example.com` via SSH, which is in the same subnet as the LDAP server and can therefore bind to it.

My go-to way of solving this is creating a SOCKS proxy using the following command on `mypc.example.org`:

```
ssh -D 8080 user@portal.subnet.example.com
```

I then configure the software to use this SOCKS proxy. This works very well with e.g. Firefox.

However, it does not seem to work with Apache Directory Studio. I have made the following settings in  "Window" > "Preferences" > "General" > "Network Connections":

- Active Provider: Manual
- Proxy entries:

  - HTTP *(nothing specified here, but I can't delete it either)*
  - HTTPS *(same as above)*
  - SOCKS: Host `localhost`, Port `8080`, Provider `Manual`, Auth `No`
- Proxy bypass:

  - `localhost`, Provider `Manual` *(default settings, I did not modify this)*
  - `127.0.0.1`, Provider `Manual` *(default settings, I did not modify this)*

Still, when I try to connect to the server, "Open Connection: (14%)" appears for a while in the bottom left corner before I get an "Error while opening connection - MSG_04177_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT (5000)".

I have also tried to set the proxy in the `ApacheDirectoryStudio.ini`, again, without success.

```
-vmargs
-DsocksProxyHost=localhost
-DsocksProxyPort=8080
```

[This issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSTUDIO-846) might be related – the last comment leaves me with the impression that the Apache LDAP API simply ignores those settings because it is based on Apache MINA, which is configured differently; I however have not found out how. [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19487363/6377268) matches the problem described in the issue, but sadly, the solutions are code - I need a configuration solution.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but you are bypassing the proxy entries on `localhost` (via `Proxy bypass`) even though the proxy itself is running on `localhost` (`Proxy entries`)? This doesn't seem to make much sense to me.

Comment: @Anaksunaman The bypass entries were default entries. I just removed them, but the problem persists. I assume they don't mean that proxies running on `localhost` should be bypassed, but that for LDAP servers running on `localhost` no proxy should be used (which I suppose is sensible, but shouldn't affect me if I'm correct, because my LDAP server does not run on `localhost`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My way of solving this would be by using SSH tunneling.

Assuming that the standard LDAP port `389` is used:

```
ssh -L 389:ldap.subnet.example.com:389 user@portal.subnet.example.com
```

This means that, on your host `mypc.example.org`, all traffic coming through the local port `389` will be sent to the SSH server `portal.subnet.example.com`, then forwarded to the remote destination `ldap.subnet.example.com` at port `389` (which the SSH server has access to).

Queries will then use the local address and port: `ldap://localhost:389` or `ldap://mypc.example.org:389`.

No proxy used, and the SSH tunnel is transparent to Apache Directory Studio.

N.B.: Here I suggest the local port `389` (such as in `ssh -L 389:`) for convenience but you may use any arbitrary available local port number.

Comment: This is indeed what I actually went with in the end, just never found the time to write a proper answer. Thanks a lot!